# Need help setting up an InDesign document trim, bleed, and live size

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

PRINT Specifications

Trim Size:      7.5”w X 10”h

Bleed Size:     7.75”w x 10.25”h

Live Area:      6.5” w x 9.25” H add a .25 pt black rule frame

Digital SPECIFICATIONS

SIZE:              468 X 60 pixels

Comment: Please start by reading the [how to](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/how-to/new-document-in-indesign.html) and the [user guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/user-guide.html/indesign/using/create-documents.ug.html) at Adobe's help site. There are also tons of other resources like [this](https://indesignskills.com/skills/indesign-basics-creating-your-first-document/). If you still have problems setting up the document, please edit your question to make it clear exactly what you struggle with.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? You can *easily* input all of those dimensions when creating a new document. - 7.5x10" document, 1/8" bleed, 1/2" margins.... The "Size: pixels" line is **not** related any print production.